# How To Retrieve Data From Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a value from database and put it in a textbox. 
I tried:

```
<input type="text" name="Balance" value="<?php $Balance= $_GET["Balance"]; ?>" readonly = "true" />
```

and:

```
 <input type="text" name="Balance" value="<?php echo $Balance; ?>" readonly = "true" />
```

But I am getting an error saying that Balance is undefined.

The php script is located in another page (connect.php) and I already put the

```
<form method="post" action="connect.php" >
```

What else should I do?

TIA

Comment: It seems you need: [How do PHP and MySQL work together?](http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/php_mysql_4.htm)

Comment: The first line won't print anything, even if your variables are defined. The second line assumes `$Balance` is defined, which apparently it is not.  What is the variable that holds the data that you've retrieved from the database?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your form method is `POST`, so:

```
... $Balance= $_POST["Balance"]; ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont know anything about what you are currently doing.

$_GET is not used to fetch something from a Database, it is used to pass and fetch parameters via URL. For accessing a Database, you need mysqli or PDO. Look for some tutorials.

Example for the code you need:

```
$sql = "SELECT balance FROM mytable";
$result = $db->Execute($sql);

echo "<input type='text' name='Balance' value='" . $result . "' readonly/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for you to get an idea:

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '')
and mysql_select_db('accounting')
and ($res = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`balance` FROM `accounts`"))
and ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res));
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Balance" value="<?= $row->balance ?>" >
```

It won't work on your computer, because I don't know the tables you're using and other things I need to know, and anyway, do a search, this topic probably has been covered a million times in the last 10-15 years since PHP exists, long before Stack Overflow existed.

PS: That's one of the oldest ways of doing it. There are other ways, like PDO, but I use the "old" way and am happy with it.